# Generating report or spreadsheet from simple XML listing of data

Tags: c#, excel, xml, xslt, reporting

I have XML objects that hold form data from a web application. These are as simple as can be for an xml format, a demonstrative example would be:

```
    <data>
        <patientFirstName>Bob</patientFirstName>
        <patientLastName>Bobson</patientLastName>
    </data>
```

and unfortunately due to humans beyond my control, roughly 150 other potential fields for the current "document".

The primary goal is to transfer this data from XML to a more "human-friendly" format such as a spreadsheet or PDF, etc..

I have tried using a DataSet as the source for a DataGrid and producing an html table. This works for a browser, and technically loads in Excel - but Excel gives a file type error, as the file is not in Excel format, it is literally an HTML table.

Is there any way to use the .net framework, or other MS objects whether managed or (preferably) unmanaged to take XML or a DataSet and turn it into a useable file format by typical office applications?

Is there a way to use SSRS without SQL queries or files? My big issue is this is a small Information System that does many things dynamically. I have seen examples of creating Excel spreadsheets using a file on the disk...but it is 2019 - I will allow my code to create or read files, the concept of a file is quite obsolete and a major source of security dilemmas.

In a perfect world I would want to create a decent looking report form template and simply bind certain nodes to their respective node in the XML. This would seem like something that many people would want to do, and as if it would be easy to implement, but search as much as I may and I find 99 terrible ways to pretend to make an Excel file and not 1 decent one.  SSRS would seem like a lovely option if I could request to use a premade template and pump XML into it or a DataSet from a middleware server - though my issue is that it seems to be dumbed-down to the point it is designed to do ALL the work in some not-very-flexible manner.

If all else fails, might there be some MS functionality for pagination that I can use to create my own mini-report generator? I feel I may be forced to..

Please understand I am not looking to hand-parse markup in C# - in unmanaged C++ I would consider it, but C# becomes very slow when you start doing things "by hand" as opposed to using objects and their methods.

.net 4.5+

Comment: I would like to note that while there are MANY options listed on this site I have yet to find a valid option. It is simple data that can be used in columns and rows, one would think there would be 18 different ways to smoothly pump it out into a common document format..

Comment: How about producing a file in the [Excel 2002/2003 XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats)? Also, I think Excel can easily consume a .csv file - but I am not an Excel user.